# Perl script works with -w switch but not without

Tags: perl, warnings, switch-statement

This script works on localhost with the `-w` switch but not without. It also works when `use strict` and `use warning` are active.

apache2/error.log:

without switch (aborted script):

```
(2)No such file or directory: exec of ... failed
```

with the switch I get:

```
Use of uninitialized value $email_flag in string ne ...
```

which looks initialised to me.

On the live web server neither one works. Perl is new to me, but I know some BASH and PHP.

I run Debian Lenny, Apache2, Perl 5.10.

```perl
#!/usr/bin/perl -w

$| = 1;

my $mailprog = '/usr/sbin/sendmail'; # where the mail program lives

my $to = "not\@for.you";   # where the mail is sent

my ($command,$email,@pairs,$buffer,$pair,$email_flag) ;

 read(STDIN, $buffer, $ENV{'CONTENT_LENGTH'});

        @pairs = split(/&/, $buffer);
       foreach $pair (@pairs) {

        # Split the pair up into individual variables.                       #
        my($name, $value) = split(/=/, $pair);

        # Decode the form encoding on the name and value variables.          #
        $name =~ tr/+/ /;
        $name =~ s/%([a-fA-F0-9][a-fA-F0-9])/pack("C", hex($1))/eg;

        $value =~ tr/+/ /;
        $value =~ s/%([a-fA-F0-9][a-fA-F0-9])/pack("C", hex($1))/eg;

        # If they try to include server side includes, erase them, so they
        # aren't a security risk if the html gets returned.  Another 
        # security hole plugged up.
        $value =~ s/<!--(.|\n)*-->//g;

     ##  print "Name of form element is $name with value of $value \n";

        if ($name eq 'email') {
            $email = $value;
           }

        if ($name eq 'command') {
            $command = $value;
           }

       }

    if ($email =~ /(@.*@)|(\.\.)|(@\.)|(\.@)|(^\.)/ ||
        $email !~ /^.+\@(\[?)[a-zA-Z0-9\-\.]+\.([a-zA-Z]{2,3}|[0-9]{1,3})(\]?)$/ ) {
        $email_flag = "ERROR";

    }

my $urlcommand = $command;


if ($command eq 'Subscribe') {
$command = "SUBSCRIBE rpc-news";
}

if ($command eq 'Unsubscribe') {
$command = "UNSUBSCRIBE rpc-news";
}

if ($command eq 'Suspend') {
$command = "SET rpc-news NOMAIL";
}

if ($command eq 'Resume') {
$command = "SET rpc-news MAIL";
}

my $getInfo = '';

print "Content-Type: text/html\n";

  if ($email_flag ne "ERROR") {

    open(MAIL,"|$mailprog -t");
     print MAIL "To: $to\n";
     print MAIL "From: $email\n";
     print MAIL "Subject: [rpc-news] $command \n";
     print MAIL "Reply-to: $email \n";

     print MAIL "$command \n";
     print MAIL "EXIT \n";
    close (MAIL);

    $getInfo = "?result=good";
   }
if ($email_flag eq "ERROR") {
    $getInfo = "?result=bad";
}   

my $rootURL= $ENV{'SERVER_NAME'};
my $url = "http://${rootURL}/thank_you.html${getInfo}&action=${urlcommand}";

print "Location: $url\n\n";
```

Comment: not sure why the formatting of the code doesnt work for the whole script.

Comment: Because you must select all code and apply code formatting. Tag you have used is only useful in one line code, block of code use spacing to format.

Comment: see [How do I format my code blocks?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks) for formatting help

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Did you create your script on a Windows machine and upload it to a Linux server without fixing the line endings?  Without the -w switch, the shebang line may look like "`#!/usr/bin/perl\r`", so the system goes looking for a program named "perl\r" (or however the line ending looks).  With the -w switch, "`#!/usr/bin/perl`" doesn't have an indecipherable line ending stuck to it.  Instead, that gets stuck to -w where it doesn't cause failure.

I thought there was a perlfaq about this, but I can't seem to find it in the docs at the moment.

Update: I found it over on PerlMonks, in a really old Q&A topic that seems unrelated until you read the body of the message: [Answer: How to get rid of premature end of script headers](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=356519).  Yeah, I know, if you were just browsing threads you wouldn't even stop on that one.  But here's the text of the post:

> If you developed this script on
>   Windows, it's possible that the script
>   file has non-UNIX line endings. (The
>   perl interpreter can handle them, but
>   the shebang line is interpreted by the
>   shell, and is not tolerant of
>   incorrect line endings.) If this is
>   the problem, the script may terminate
>   with an error right at the shebang
>   line.

Comment: Indeed, the original file was edited with Dreamweaver on Windows. i now work on debian with kwrite, but cat -A shows `#!/usr/bin/perl^M$`

Comment: dos2unix fixes this. the debian package is named: tofrodos . Thanks a ton.

Answer (score 3):

> `Use of uninitialized value $email_flag in string ne ...`
>
> which looks initialised to me.
>
> ```
>  if ($email =~ /(@.*@)|(\.\.)|(@\.)|(\.@)|(^\.)/ ||
>      $email !~ /^.+\@(\[?)[a-zA-Z0-9\-\.]+\.([a-zA-Z]{2,3}|[0-9]{1,3})(\]?)$/
>  ) {
>      $email_flag = "ERROR"; 
>  }
> ```

$email_flag only gets initialized here if the pattern matches - otherwise it's left undefined. You could add an `else` clause to ensure it gets initialized no matter what.

Comment: Or define and initialize it: `my $email_flag = "";` (obviously, separating it from the other variables currently defined at the same time).

Comment: `my ($command,$email,@pairs,$buffer,$pair,$email_flag) ;`
i thought that line up the top initialises the $email_flag

Comment: @mario - That line doesn't initialize the variables, it simply declares them, leaving their value as undef.

Answer (score 0):

I would not use that code, it doesn't use CGI.pm (or CGI::Simple ...)
Get "TFMail -- Improved Form Mail" from "nms - web programs written by experts"

Its simple to install, and its written well ( it uses CGI ...)